# How to remove future broken image using jquery

Tags: jquery

will normally, this will work..

```
$("img").error(function(){$(this).hide();});
```

but it doesnt work when putting a live on it

```
$("img").live("error",function(){$(this).hide();});
```

the problem is that, for those image which are ajax generated, i cannot hide the broken image.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the event handler as you add the images to the DOM:

```
$.get(urlHere, function(htmlData) {
    var output = $(htmlData).find('img').error(function () {$(this).hide();}).end();
    $(<selector>).html(output);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3nXcS/2/

**Update**

When you `console.log()` the `e.bubbles` variable it returns `false`. So you can't use a binding method that requires bubbling (`.delegate()`, `.live()`).

Comment: This will only output the `img` elements. Any other elements in the `htmlData` will be lost. Use this instead: `var output = $(htmlData); output.filter('img').error(function () {$(this).hide();}); $(<selector>).html(output);`. Regardless, I think this is precisely what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: @JosephSilber Good catch, I added `.end()` to the end of the jQuery chain to return the the parent selector. The benefit to this method is that it only binds the events to the elements necessary, no bubbling needed which is a performance benefit.

Comment: Well, event bubbling occurs regardless of whether you've attached an event handler... Actually, I think in this particular case, `live` would be better for performance, since you only bind the event handler on 1 element (the `document`).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3nXcS/3/ The `error` event does not bubble up to the document.

Comment: yeahh.. thanks for the demo.. i thought there is an easier to do that just like adding a live() .. but anyways, i appreciated your help.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `$("img").live` method is supposed to work, if not you can try `livequery`([Livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery))

Try,

```
$("img").livequery('error', function(){$(this).hide();})
```

Comment: it still doesn;t work.. i tried putting an alert jsut to know if it triggers, but no alert happen..